# Use jmeter with Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, jmeter, virtualbox

i have a question regarding the use of jmeter in a virtualbox.
 I try to use jmeter with remote tests in a VPN and because this makes some problems which are to hard to solve for some of my remote clients, i decided to try designing a predefined ubuntu version in Virtualbox (13.04, 32 bit), so the only thing the clients will have to do is start the virtual Ubuntu and everthing should work.

My normal Ubuntu (12.04, 64bit) is the Master and it should distribute the tests to remote computers where the virtual Ubuntus are running. Now I have already set up the virtualbox and i can Ping in both directions and i've got internet connection, but jmeter still gets a ConnectException when I try to start a remote test.

I have disabled the firewall and I am using a networkbridge.

Has anybody an idea what could still be missing?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that for remote JMeter engines RMI hostnames may be defaulting to localhost and need to be amended as follows:

```
java.rmi.server.hostname=169.168.167.166
```

The property can be also set as a command-line argument to JMeter startup script being prefixed by `-D` as

```
jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=169.168.167.166
```

References:

- [Remote(Distributed) Testing Guide](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)